# Error Inserting Photo from Drawable using MySQLHelper

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm currently facing difficulty getting a specific image to appear, and after looking at the error messages I can't decipher why it's not showing up at all.

Here's the LogCat:

```
03-28 13:45:49.552: E/SpannableStringBuilder(21649): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
03-28 13:45:49.552: E/SpannableStringBuilder(21649): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
03-28 13:45:53.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(21649): Error inserting photo=[B@433d3d88 name=Chord Name: A-7th
03-28 13:45:53.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(21649): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: column name is not unique (code 19)
03-28 13:45:53.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(21649):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
03-28 13:45:53.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(21649):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:905)
03-28 13:45:53.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(21649):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
03-28 13:45:53.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(21649):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
03-28 13:45:53.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(21649):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
03-28 13:45:53.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(21649):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
03-28 13:45:53.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(21649):    at com.finalyearproject.MySQLiteHelper.insertCrdDetails(MySQLiteHelper.java:77)
03-28 13:45:53.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(21649):    at com.finalyearproject.ChordImages.onCreate(ChordImages.java:63)
03-28 13:45:53.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(21649):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
03-28 13:45:53.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(21649):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
03-28 13:45:53.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(21649):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
03-28 13:45:53.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(21649):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
03-28 13:45:53.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(21649):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
03-28 13:45:53.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(21649):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
03-28 13:45:53.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(21649):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-28 13:45:53.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(21649):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-28 13:45:53.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(21649):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
03-28 13:45:53.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(21649):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 13:45:53.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(21649):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-28 13:45:53.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(21649):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
03-28 13:45:53.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(21649):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
03-28 13:45:53.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(21649):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-28 13:45:53.182: E/SpannableStringBuilder(21649): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
03-28 13:45:53.182: E/SpannableStringBuilder(21649): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
```

I noticed from the LogCat file that there's an error with my `ChordImages.onCreate` method and also within my `MySQLiteHelper.getCrdDetails` method upon looking through these files I'm stumped as to what's causing the issue. Just wondering if anyone could have a read through the code and let me know if you can spot anything blatently obvious.

ChordImages.java:

```
package com.finalyearproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ChordImages extends Activity {
 private MySQLiteHelper DbHelper;

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.chordview);

      DbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
      Chords A7th = new Chords(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a_7), "A-7th");

    /*  DbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
      Chords A_Maj = new Chords(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a_maj), "Chord: A-Major");

      DbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
      Chords A_Min = new Chords(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a_min), "Chord: A-Minor");

      DbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
      Chords B_7th = new Chords(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.b_7), "Chord: B-7th");

      DbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
      Chords C_7th = new Chords(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.c_7), "Chord: C-7th");

      DbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
      Chords C_Maj = new Chords(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.c_maj), "Chord: C-Major");

      DbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
      Chords D_7th = new Chords(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.d_7), "Chord: D-7th");

      DbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
      Chords D_Maj = new Chords(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.d_maj), "Chord: D-Major");

      DbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
      Chords D_Min = new Chords(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.d_min), "Chord: D-Minor");

      DbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
      Chords E_7th = new Chords(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.e_7), "Chord: E-7th");

      DbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
      Chords E_Maj = new Chords(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.e_maj), "Chord: E-Major");

      DbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
      Chords E_Min = new Chords(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.e_min), "Chord: E-Minor");

      DbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
      Chords F_Maj = new Chords(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.f_maj), "Chord: F-Major");

      DbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
      Chords G_7th = new Chords(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.g_7), "Chord: G-7th");

      DbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
      Chords G_Maj = new Chords(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.g_maj), "Chord: G-Major"); */


      DbHelper.open();
      DbHelper.insertCrdDetails(A7th);
      DbHelper.close();
      A7th = null;
      DbHelper.open();
      A7th = DbHelper.retriveCrdDetails();
      DbHelper.close();

  TextView crdname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
  crdname.setText(A7th.getName());

  ImageView crdphoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo);
  crdphoto.setImageBitmap(A7th.getBitmap());
  }
}
```

MySQLiteHelper.java:

```
package com.finalyearproject;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class MySQLiteHelper {

    public static final String CRD_ID = "id";
    public static final String CRD_NAME = "name";
    public static final String CRD_PHOTO = "photo";

    private DatabaseHelper mMySQLiteHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ChordDB.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String CHORD_TABLE = "Chords";

    private static final String CREATE_CHORD_TABLE = "create table "
            + CHORD_TABLE + " (" + CRD_ID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + CRD_PHOTO
            + " blob not null, " + CRD_NAME + " text not null );";


    private final Context mCtx;

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL(CREATE_CHORD_TABLE);
  }

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CHORD_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
  }
 }

public void Reset() {

    mMySQLiteHelper.onUpgrade(this.mDb, 1, 1);
 }

public MySQLiteHelper(Context ctx) {

      mCtx = ctx;
      mMySQLiteHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
 }

public MySQLiteHelper open() throws SQLException {

    mDb = mMySQLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
 }

public void close() {

    mMySQLiteHelper.close();
 }

public void insertCrdDetails(Chords chord) {

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(CRD_PHOTO, Utility.getBytes(chord.getBitmap()));
    cv.put(CRD_NAME, chord.getName());
    mDb.insert(CHORD_TABLE, null, cv);
 }

public Chords retriveCrdDetails() throws SQLException {

    Cursor cur = mDb.query(true, CHORD_TABLE, new String[] { CRD_PHOTO, CRD_NAME }, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            byte[] blob = cur.getBlob(cur.getColumnIndex(CRD_PHOTO));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(CRD_NAME));
            cur.close();

            return new Chords(Utility.getPhoto(blob), name);
  }
        cur.close();
        return null;
 }
}
```

Slowly but surely learning how to deal with this myself, but I've been looking at this issue since last night and can't seem to get the image I want to show. All my Image files are contained in the `Drawable` folder.

Comment: im not sure but you dont set the id of Chord anywhere in your code?!

Comment: @Dima Because the ID of the chord in the database is set as the primary key it should automatically increment by 1 for every new entry to the database? That's what I was told when creating it, unsure how else I would add unique IDs to each Chord

Comment: UUID.randomUUID(). As i said, im not sure about it, but your logcat says, that your column is not unique

Comment: @Dima I'm really new to all this android development currently working off tutorials and my basic knowledge of java from first year in University. Very steep learning curve for me! Wouldn't know how to fix the fact the column isn't unique